# Using jodd Java framework in netbeans web application project

Tags: netbeans-8, jodd

I'm currently following the jodd example from jodd website, instead of using gradle I'm creating a web application project in netbeans and adding required jodd jars this the project. The reason I'm using this approach is that I can't open the examples in netbeans even though I'm using the netbeans gradle plugin but I'm still trying to get this sorted, this is my first problem.

My second problem is that when I look at the directory structure of the example and the directory structure my own setup, the app.props file is not found when I run the project from the IDE hence the project is not deployed to tomcat. I tried mimicking the example projects directory structure but still resources\app.props is not found and I don't know where go from here.

Please guys help me.

Comment: Are you sure that you have all the dependencies? Also, you might want to check with their mailing list for advice on using it w/Netbeans. I'm sure you're not the first to try.

Comment: @Vuzi which example you are looking for?

Comment: @Vuzi do gradle examples work from command line for you?

Comment: @игор I'm following this one:http://joddframework.org. I'll test from command line today, when I get my machine. I should've tested, oversight on my side. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a NetBeans user, and I never understood how it works, but what I can suggest you is the following:

1. First make sure project compiles from command line, using `gradle`. For example, download source from [step #2](http://joddframework.org/), unzip it to some folder and run `gradlew build`. This should work.
2. Note that gradle is using the Maven folder structure. There is nothing specific with that. This means that NetBeans should be aware at some point of configuration about this structure.
3. Try to build a war first in NetBeans and then deploy it to Tomcat. I guess NetBeans is capable of build wars :)
4. Shoudn't be there a way how to mark a resource folder for a web project in NetBeans?
5. **important**: some IDEs have some default set of extensions that are considered as 'resources', like `.properties`, `.xml` etc. This may be the reason why NetBeans is not seeing `app.props` as a resource file. So try to find this configuration in NetBeans and change it to also accept the `*.props` files.

   For the test, just add some `foo.properties` in resource folder next to `app.props` and check if it gets packaged.
6. Install IntelliJ IDEA :)

Comment: Thanks alot again for your input. Will follow your advice but can only get to it on the weekend. The reason why i Used netbeans was the autocompletion capabilities in the jsp when using jodd tag libs. Il try intellij, I've installed CE Edition. Will give you feedback as soon as i can. Your help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: turns out gradle was corrupted, I ran gradlew build I'm cmd line and it didn't run, so I deleted .cradle folder in project and user directories and the build ran successfully. I downloaded intellij as you suggested but i could open the project with proper folder structure with resources folder with app.props in netbeans. The example is compiles successfully but how do I go about deploy this to tomcat? Should I append the .build file to cater for deployment or can I run this example as is? I checked there's a gradle-tomcat plugin available, what's the best approach in your view?

Comment: @Vuzi usually gradle plugin should be enough to integrate with your IDE in such way to enable the deployments. Meanwhile, you can always generate WAR with gradle and deploy manually or through the Netbeans. In IntelliJ when you open a gradle project, everything is already set. Hope this helps;)

Comment: forgive my pestering. Could you please give me the steps to run the examples in intellij.

Comment: @Vuzi see: http://jodd.org/code.html It's very easy: 1) open the project 2) setup your Tomcat 3) set the artifact for Tomcat. But you must know how IntelliJ works, of course:) so invest some time into learning IntelliJ - this is not related to Jodd, but for all web apps.